# Efficient search in list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list

I want to search on a list and if find get its complement

E.g.:

```
l = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd')]


get_adjunct('1')
```

output

```
# u'a'
```

I know this way:

```
def search_adjunct(search)
    for item in list:
        if item[0] == search:
            return item[1]
    return search
```

Someone knows other a simple and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Convert it to a dictionary if the first item is unique and hashable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in the lines of :

```
l = [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd')]
d = dict(l)
d['1']
# 'a'
```

Without dict, a generator would give you:

```
next((item[1] for item in l if item[0] == search), None)
```

`next` returns the second argument (None) if the generator is empty

Comment: use `d.get('1')`. It returns None if the key is not present.